# How to bring a json result into PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json, ajax

I have some results from a fetch.php using json and I successfully brought all results to my bootstrap modal HTML screen. 
When the Modal is being shown, I would like to run a MYSQL query using a value coming from the same json I used for the modal, however I can't put this value into a PHP variable to run the SQL query. 
How can I get this?

I am trying to bring the same value I input into the HTML textbox (modal), but it is not working. I also tried to use the value from json '$('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);)', but nothing happen.

This is the script to collect information from database using fetch.php file:

```
<script> 

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table').on('click', '.fetch_data', function(){
          var pcr_number = $(this).attr('id');

          $.ajax({
            url:'fetch.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{pcr_number:pcr_number},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){

              $('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);
              $('#PCC').val(data.PCC);
              $('#PCR_Creation').val(data.Creation_Date);
              $('#PCR_Status').val(data.Stage);
              $('#Required_Completion').val(data.Required_Completion);
            }
          });
        });
      }); 
 </script>
```

This is the PHP code

```
<?php
       //trying to get the value I have included on #PCR (textbox) which has ID='PCR' and name ='PCR' **

        $PCR= $_POST['PCR'];

       //running now the code to check if the database has the value and return the desired response to be shown **

        $sql1 = mysqli_query($dbConnected,"SELECT * FROM change_management.tPCN");

               while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)) {
                  if ($row1['PCRNo']==$PCR){
                  echo $row1['PCNNo'];
                  echo "<br/>";
                 }else{

                }
              }       
?>
```

I would like include value from this `val(data.PCRNo)` json return into the $PCR variable, so the MYSQL query is going to work

Comment: The parameter you sent is called pcr_number, not PCR. They have to match up, the computer can't guess what you meant

Comment: And the data you are echoing in return is not JSON, so jQuery will not understand it. You seem to be outputting HTML instead

Comment: debugging tip, try printing the $_POST array once to see the array structure, the dataType parameter is used to specify the return type of the data, not the outgoing one

Comment: I think you need to double check your code, and also check that you understand what JSON is and how to generate it using PHP. There are lots of simple tutorials you can follow.

Comment: Thanks for the first comments @ADyson and @pinaki, one thing that I confuse is why I can use the code `$('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);` and include this value in my HTML and I can't get this value to insert in a PHP variable.

Comment: Because those are two completely different and independent things. You can access your form field using `$('#PCR')`, because you gave the form field the ID `PCR`. The name of the POST parameter you are sending, _you yourself_ specified as `pcr_number` - that is the first `pcr_number` in `data:{pcr_number:pcr_number}` The keys you use in that object you are passing for `data` here, determine the names of the POST parameters you are sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of quite basic logical issues with your code which are preventing it from working.

1) `data: { pcr_number: pcr_number}`- the name `pcr_number` doesn't match the value `PCR` which the server is searching for using `$_POST['PCR'];`. The names must match up. When making an AJAX request, the name you gave to the form field in the HTML does not matter (unless you use `.serialize()`) because you are specifying new names in the `data` parameter.

2) Your SQL query doesn't make sense. You seem to be wanting to read a single row relating to a PCR number, yet your query makes no usage of the input `PCR` value to try and restrict the results to that row. You need to use a SQL `WHERE` clause to get it to select only the row with that ID, otherwise you'll fetch all the rows and won't know which one is correct. (Fetching them all and then using an `if` in a PHP loop to check the correct one is very inefficient.) I wrote you a version which uses the WHERE clause properly, and passes the PCR value to the query securely using prepared statements and parameters (to project against SQL injection attacks).

3) Your output from the PHP also makes no sense. You've told jQuery (via `dataType: "json"` to expect a JSON response, and then your code inside the "success" function is based on the assumption you'll receive a single object containing all the fields from the table. But `echo $row1['PCNNo']; echo "<br/>";` only outputs one field, and it outputs it with HTML next to it. This is not JSON, it's not even close to being JSON. You need to output the whole row, and then use `json_encode()` function to turn the object into a JSON string which jQuery can parse when it receives it.

Here's a version of the code containing all the above changes:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table').on('click', '.fetch_data', function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: { pcr: $(this).attr('id'); },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
          $('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);
          $('#PCC').val(data.PCC);
          $('#PCR_Creation').val(data.Creation_Date);
          $('#PCR_Status').val(data.Stage);
          $('#Required_Completion').val(data.Required_Completion);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$PCR = $_POST['pcr'];

$stmt = $dbConnected->prepare("SELECT * FROM change_management.tPCN WHERE PCRNo = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $PCR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//an "if" here will cause a single row to be read
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output = $row;
}
else
{
    $output = new StdClass();
}

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

//output the result
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

N.B. I would potentially suggest studying some tutorials on this kind of subject, since this is a fairly standard use case for AJAX/JSON, and you should be able to find samples which would improve your understanding of all the different parts.

P.S. Currently the PHP code above will return an empty object if there is no matching row in the database. However, this is probably an error condition (and will cause your JavaScript code to crash due to trying to read nonexistent properties), so you should consider how you want to handle such an error and what response to return (e.g. 400, or 404, and a suitable message).

Comment: You should think all doesn't  make sense because the instruction is to don't put the whole code, so I just resumed what I am working on. The MYSQL query is working fine in another page, so I  am not worried about this, my concern is how to storage the value of the PCR, which I click in a table to send it to a fetch, in one PHP  variable like `$PCR` and use this to run mySQL query.

Comment: Well I've shown you how to send the value to the server, and I've shown you how to use it in a SQL query. Your query might work somewhere else but it wasn't logical in this situation (that's not the same as it not working!). So, does the code I've posted work for you and produce the expected result? And did you understand the points I made, to learn from later?

Comment: Hello @ADyson, it didn't help me. you are trying to complain instead of understanding my real problem. I understand the points I need to study and learn, thanks for that. I believe my post is a bit confusing, so I create another one which is related to the same issue, however can solve it too. See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378673/how-to-bring-more-than-one-row-mysql-result-inside-the-same-variable-when-runn?noredirect=1#comment101243429_57378673). Thanks a lot

Comment: I agree I don't think maybe you articulated your issue too clearly. I answered what I thought was the question, but apologies if it wasn't helpful. I will look at your new post, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first return json from php by using `json_encode`.

Inside this loop

```
while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)) {
 $data = array('PCRNo' => 'itsvalue', 'PCC' => 'itsvalue', 'Creation_Date' => 'itsvalue')
}

print json_encode($data)
```

store all the data in an associative array and then convert it into json using `json_encode` and return the json.

Use json data in you ajax file

```
$.ajax({
        url:'fetch.php',
        method:'post',
        data:{pcr_number:pcr_number},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
          var data = JSON.parse(data);
          $('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);
          $('#PCC').val(data.PCC);
          $('#PCR_Creation').val(data.Creation_Date);
          $('#PCR_Status').val(data.Stage);
          $('#Required_Completion').val(data.Required_Completion);
        }
      });
```

Comment: @vinay_kumar what should I include in the `json_encode` to get the value from the fetch.php file? Would be the input `pcr_number` I send to fetch.php file or the output `val(data.PCRNo) ` which I used to fill in my HTML?

Comment: I tried your codes, but still something missed. I am trying to be very simple. let's get the sequence I would like to do. I have my table and I click on the "PCR Number" and it is storage at `var pcr_number = $(this).attr('id');`. Perfect by now. After this this value go to fetch.php and find the pcr_number in the database and return inside a `json` array with the same value we sent to the fetch file but in another format `$('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);` which I used to fill in my bootstrap modal HTML inside PCR Number text box the name and ID are `"PCR"` . (cont.)

Comment: ... What I really need is a way to storage the PCR Number in one `$PCR` variable and use this value to run another MySQL query and get other information. How can I store this PCR number I clicked on in one PHP variable?

Comment: @EL.ALEX78UK check my new answer

Answer (score 1):

Below is the changed script to store different values in $PCR variable

```
  <script> 

  $(document).ready(function(){
       var i = 1;
        $('#table').on('click', '.fetch_data', function(){
          if(i == 1) {
            var pcr_number = $(this).attr('id');
          } else {
            var pcr_number = $('#PCR').val();
          }

          $.ajax({
            url:'fetch.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{pcr_number:pcr_number},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){

              $('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);
              $('#PCC').val(data.PCC);
              $('#PCR_Creation').val(data.Creation_Date);
              $('#PCR_Status').val(data.Stage);
              $('#Required_Completion').val(data.Required_Completion);
              i++;
            }
          });
        });
      }); 
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi @vinay kumar , I have made another post I believe will help me more, because I believe this one is very confusing. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378673/how-to-bring-more-than-one-row-mysql-result-inside-the-same-variable-when-runn?noredirect=1#comment101243429_57378673). If you sort that one you will sort this one too :-) . Thanks.