# How to bring more than one row (mysql) result inside the same variable when running a json_encode?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, ajax

I am running a POST + json code to collect data from database, all results come with only one value (this is correct), however there is only one column which should show more than one value but shows only the first one. What I need to change in my code to get this list instead of the first row result?

I've run one MYSQL query linking three databases those share the same id `PCRNo`, the first two databases `tPCR` and `tcomplement` should only have one result and the third one should receive more results due to we can have more lines with the same id.

This is my JavaScript

```
<script> 

  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#table').on('click', '.fetch_data', function(){
          var pcr_number = $(this).attr('id');

          $.ajax({
            url:'fetch.php',
            method:'post',
            data:{pcr_number:pcr_number},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){

              $('#PCR').val(data.PCRNo);
              $('#PCC').val(data.PCC);
              $('#PCR_Creation').val(data.Creation_Date);
              $('#PCR_Status').val(data.Stage);
              $('#Required_Completion').val(data.Required_Completion);
              $('#description').val(data.Name);
              $('#Comments').val(data.Comments);
              $('#originator').val(data.Creator);
              $('#change_type').val(data.Category);
              $('#product_type').val(data.Product);
              $('#req_dept').val(data.Department);
              $('#flow').val(data.Flow_Start_Date);
              $('#own').val(data.Owning_Site);
              $('#impacted').val(data.Impacted_Site);
              $('#approval').val(data.Meeting_Status);
              $('#review').val(data.Review_Date);
              $('#cat').val(data.Cat);
              $('#cost').val(data.Cost);
              $('#labor').val(data.Labour);
              $('#volume').val(data.Volume);
              $('#request').val(data.Request);
              $('#justification').val(data.Justification);
              $('#PCNlist').val(data.PCNNo);
              $('#monitor').val(data.Monitor);
              $('#env').val(data.Environment);
              $('#trial').val(data.Trial);
              $('#resp').val(data.Responsible);
              $('#deadline').val(data.Deadline);      
              $('#dataModal').modal('show');

            }
          });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#update', function(){  
        var pcr_number = document.getElementById("PCR").value;  
        var Comments= document.getElementById("Comments").value; 
        var approval= document.getElementById("approval").value;
        var review= document.getElementById("review").value;
        var cat= document.getElementById("cat").value;
        var monitor= document.getElementById("monitor").value;
        var env= document.getElementById("env").value;
        var trial= document.getElementById("trial").value;
        var resp= document.getElementById("resp").value; 
        var deadline= document.getElementById("deadline").value;
        var PCC = document.getElementById("PCC").value;


        $.ajax({  
            url:"edit.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{pcr_number:pcr_number, Comments:Comments, PCC:PCC, approval:approval, review:review, cat:cat, monitor:monitor, env:env, trial:trial, resp:resp, deadline:deadline},  
            dataType:"text",
            success:function(data)  
            {  
                alert('PCR Information Updated');  

            }

        });  
        });
  }); 
 </script>
```

this is my fetch.php

```php
<?php
$SelectedPCRNo = $_POST['pcr_number'];
if(isset($_POST['pcr_number']))
{
  $output = '';
  $hostname = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";

  $databaseName = "change_management";

  $dbConnected = @mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
  $dbSelected = @mysqli_select_db($databaseName,$dbConnected);

  $dbSuccess = true;
  if ($dbConnected) {
    if ($dbSelected) {
      echo "DB connection FAILED<br /><br />";
      $dbSuccess = false;
    }       
  } else {
    echo "MySQL connection FAILED<br /><br />";
    $dbSuccess = false;
  }

  $sql = mysqli_query($dbConnected, "SELECT *   FROM change_management.tPCR INNER JOIN change_management.tcomplement ON change_management.tPCR.PCRNo = change_management.tcomplement.PCRNo INNER JOIN change_management.tPCN ON change_management.tPCR.PCRNo = change_management.tPCN.PCRNo WHERE tPCR.PCRNo = '".$_POST['pcr_number']."'");  

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);     
  echo json_encode($row); 
}  
 ?>
```

I have no problems with the results and the table is filled OK, only the `#PCNlist` should be filled with the values of all rows it is related and now just is just coming one value, the first row only. Is there any way to bring the whole PCNlist only changing some code at the fetch.php?

Comment: You need to loop the `fetch`, or use `fetchall`. You also are open to SQL injections. Additionally you also don't need the database on all table references. You already are in the DB based on your DB connection.

Comment: Your code is very vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements. Do not silence errors with the `@` operator.

Comment: I understand it is a bit vulnerable, however, it will be an intranet only to be used by my team, I don't need to spend months of development, I am trying to be functional. I've done a lot, but this issue is really concerning me because I believe I need more knowledge and I don't have it now. So any help with the solution will be really appreciated.

Comment: protecting against SQL injection won't take months of development, it takes a few small adjustments to your code. If you do it correctly the first time, it won't cost you any extra time, especially once you get used to it. https://bobby-tables.com/php has some simple examples of how to write your queries securely. So does the PHP documentation. It's worth your time for when you come to write a more widely used application. Also you shouldn't assume your team will forever be trustworthy, or that their machines can't be compromised.

Comment: For the same reason, never allow a web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for attacks.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup

Comment: There's no excuse for poor security practice, even on an intranet application. Don't be fooled into thinking your firewall can protect you against all kinds of threat, or that "your team" are all angels, and can never be the victim of some kind of malware or phishing attack. Generally in any enterprise, the biggest IT security threat comes (unintentionally) from the employees.

Comment: Are you just trying to get this to work then you will pay attention to optimisation and security or is optimisation and security not a concern for you at all?

Comment: @WMRamadan , I am first trying to make this works, I was planning to include users and passwords separately for each one. So if I make it right I can at least sell the idea internally to be implemented in my team. Thanks

Comment: @ADyson you are completely right and I will make sure I am going to incude securety on this page. But bear with me it is my first MySQL / PHP development :-) .I understand your answer regarding run another query separately for the `tPCN`, I  did kind of this see, `$sql1 = mysqli_query($dbConnected, "SELECT *   FROM change_management.tPCN WHERE tPCN.PCRNo = '".$_POST['pcr_number']."'");

  $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);   
  
  echo json_encode($row1);`

Comment: @ADyson but I don't know how to collect correctly the result inside the `$('#PCNlist').val(data.PCNNo);`

Comment: Well if you use the structure shown in my answer, then you would need to run a JavaScript `for` loop against `data.tPCN` and append each entry from the array into your PCNlist element. Do you think you can try that? (P.S. You can't json_encode() your second query's result separately - JSON is only valid if it's a single continuous array/object. If you output a series of separately-encoded pieces of JSON, then you will not be able to parse them and your JS code will crash. Instead you must create a single object, as shown in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, the table `tPCN` can contain multiple rows associated with each PCR number. And you want to fetch all these rows and return them in your JSON.

If you want to achieve that, but also make sure the other two tables only return one row, then I think simply you should remove the JOIN to `tPCN` in your first query, and then create a second query to fetch the `tPCN` rows specifically.

```
$output = [];
$stmt = $dbConnected->prepare("SELECT * FROM change_management.tPCR INNER JOIN change_management.tcomplement ON change_management.tPCR.PCRNo = change_management.tcomplement.PCRNo WHERE tPCR.PCRNo = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['pcr_number']);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

//select a single row from the result and assign it as the output variable
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output = $row;
}

$stmt2 = $dbConnected->prepare("SELECT * FROM change_management.tPCN WHERE PCRNo = ?");
$stmt2->bind_param('s', $_POST['pcr_number']);
$stmt2->execute();
$result2 = $stmt2->get_result();
$output["tPCN"] = array(); //create a new property to put the tPCN rows in

//loop through all the tPCN rows and append them to the output
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $output["tPCN"][] = $row2;
}

echo json_encode($output);
```

This will produce some JSON with this kind of structure:

```
{
  "PCRNo": "ABC",
  "CreationDate": "2019-08-07",
  "Name": "A N Other",
  //...and all your other properties, until the new one:
  "tPCN": [
    {
      "SomeProperty": "SomeValue",
      "SomeOtherProperty": "SomeOtherValue",
    },
    {
      "SomeProperty": "SomeSecondValue",
      "SomeOtherProperty": "SomeOtherSecondValue",
    }
  ]
}
```

You will then need to amend your JavaScript code to be able to deal with the new structure. Since I don't know exactly which fields come from the `tPCN` table, I can't give you an example for that, but hopefully it's clear that you will need to loop through the array and output the same HTML for each entry you find.

---

N.B. As you can see I re-wrote the query code to use prepared statements and parameterised queries, so you can see how to write your code in a secure way in future.

---

P.S. You have a lot of code there in the "success" function just to set the values of individual fields. You might want to consider using a simple JS templating engine to make this less verbose and cumbersome, and generate the HTML you need with the values automatically added into it in the right place. But that's a separate issue, just for the maintainability of your code

Comment: Thanks for this code. I have my first question; why did you include `PCRNo = ?` instead of `PCRNo='".$_POST['pcr_number']."'` ?

Comment: That's the parameterisation part, to protect you from SQL injection attacks (and also helpfully, unexpected SQL syntax errors when your input data contains things like quote marks). You can read more about it in the PHP docs (and other articles online) `?` is a parameter placeholder. Then on the next line the "bind_param" securely inserts the real data into the query string (overwriting the `?`), ensuring that any special characters are properly dealt with, to prevent people doing things like [this](https://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: (The parameter binding simply replaces the `?` characters it finds in order, so if you have multiple inputs to your query, and multiple `?`s written in the SQL string, you can write like `$stmt->bind_param('ss', $val1, $val2);` and it will replace the values in the order you provide them. Again you can read more about it in the PHP docs ([here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) are useful starting points)

Comment: I really appreciated you spend your time trying to instruct me, thanks for that. I liked this code and I would like to use it. When I change my fetch.php file to yours, everything now has stopped but become very complex to me to find the problem, I believe even I haven't created a loop for the PCNlist, the others items should go as normal, but they don't appear anymore.

Comment: I think then that your next step would be to improve your debugging skills. Ensure you know how to switch on error reporting for PHP and mysqli (you can find it on StackOverflow and elsewhere), and ensure you understand how to use your browser's Console and Network tools (in the Developer Tools) to debug the JavaScript and AJAX requests (so you can see what data is being sent and received, what the responses look like, and view any errors). Once you can see this kind of information, it's much easier to trace the root cause of a problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am going to work with this information now. Cheers!!

Comment: We are almost there!! Now, when I run the new code and I have more than one line in the `tPCN` Database that match with the `PCRNo` column, I got this result in my table, see `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. For example this request has got 4 rows matching, and it is good, only I need to realize how to transform this in values (I only need to capture te PCNNo and Stage column values for each). My JASON code has `$('#PCNlist').val(data.tPCN);` only.  I am going to learn about your JSON code you icluded above, because I didn't understand it yet. Thanks

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you see when you try to output a complex object with multiple properties in it. JavaScript has no idea how you actually want to display the properties, so it just outputs that generic format. You need to pick out the individual properties from the object and include them in the output. Also, what within my JSON structure are you struggling to understand, specifically? Perhaps I can clarify it. If you are having multiple issues with this it might make sense to ask a new question relating to usage of the JSON, then we can see your code, and more people might help

Answer (score 1):

I've added this code into my ajax function to bring only what I needed and it works + what @ADyson has posted.

```
var PCN = data.tPCN;
var i;
var PCNList = '';

for (i = 0; i < PCN.length; i++){
  var PCNList = PCNList + PCN[i]['PCNNo'] + ' - ' + PCN[i]['Stage']; 
}
$('#PCNlist').val(PCNList);
```

Comment: just a code efficiency / scoping note: don't keep re-initialising the `PCNList` variable using `var` inside your `for` loop. You've already declared it, you don't need to keep declaring it again. Also you can write the append command more neatly. You should change `var PCNList = PCNList + PCN[i]['PCNNo']....` to `PCNList += PCN[i]['PCNNo']...`. You may not notice any functional difference, but the code is more correct, and also clearer and shorter. If you did this kind of re-initialisation mistake on a large scale you could get performance problems, or issues with variable scope.

Comment: And you don't have to declare `i` separately either, instead of having `var i;` on its own you could just write `for (var i = 0; ...` directly in the loop

Comment: `var PCN = data.tPCN;` isn't really necessary either. It's somewhat a matter of personal style I guess, but you could just use the original variable directly, no need to make another one. So altogether your code could be shortened to `var PCNList = '';

for (i = 0; i < data.tPCN.length; i++){
  PCNList +=  data.tPCN[i]['PCNNo'] + ' - ' + data.tPCN[i]['Stage']; 
}
$('#PCNlist').val(PCNList);`

Comment: @ADyson thanks for the help, it was essential for this success. Now I am going to move on in other pages I still need to create. Just to let you know, I  am not a programmer, I  am an Engineering Manager trying to include new tools to my team and give up some heavy excel spreadsheets with lots of sharing issues that we have today :-). I will take all your tips to give my intranet security when I  move it to the company server. Cheers!!

Comment: Good luck with your project then, glad to have helped. You seem to be picking up the coding thing pretty quickly, with a few pointers from us, so I think you'll do a good job